# Translate CL.exe to mingw command

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, compilation, mingw

I have this CL.exe command

```
cl -Fesample.dll -Oi -LD -D NO_TRACE=1 -MT sample.cpp sample_dll.def
```

and i would like to compile it on Linux with MinGW and this is what i have so far

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc -Fesample.dll -shared -D NO_TRACE=1 sample.cpp sample_dll.def
```

Tracing down the cl command options

```
-Oi is optimisation -> not important at this point
-LD is for generating a dll -> replaced with -shared
-D is for setting a constant in the source -> same on both
-MT is for multithreading -> i was not able to find the mingw option for this as it seems it is not fully supported.
```

Am i wrong?

But it won't compile and i don't really know why.
Errors i got from testing are ether

```
-Cannot export samplefunction@4: symbol not defined
```

or when changing the command through guessing

```
-Error: invalid Suffix
-Warning: ‘somevariable’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
```

If you can help me, please do so. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at [gcc command line reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/#toc-GCC-Command-Options).

Comment: I have a similar situation with you, and I'm reading http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm

Answer (score -1):

To compile a shared library from functions in a C++ code file:

```
 g++ -o esample.so -shared -fpic -DNO_TRACE=1 sample.cpp
```

Multithreaded (`-MT`) should be the default these days.

The `-LD` equivalent is `-fpic` and `-shared`

Reference: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html